# What is a simple way to integrate AWS and GitLab to deploy an app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, gitlab, continuous-deployment

What is a simple way to deploy an app to AWS using GitLab?

**NOTE: Not using Elastic Beanstalk**

Can use EC2 and an ELB or other AWS services.

I found many blog posts about various ways of doing it but they are very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jenkins (installed in an EC2 Server) that will provide webhooks endpoint to be used by your GitLab Repo.

[More Info here.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jenkins.html)

After you connect GitLab -> Jenkins EC2 via webhooks you can just simply create a shell file that will be executed by your jenkins tasks that will then run few commands that will performs the deployment e.g. git pull, unit test, rysnc and notify to developer.

[Everytime push happens, the below pipeline will execute]
GitLab -> EC2-Jenkins (-> ssh ->) App Servers

I think that simple & flexible:)